# Offline приложение на React

Tags: reactjs, offline

Друзья, подскажите есть ли возможность создать оффлайн приложение на React ?
Это приложение типа Заметки - юзер на своем компе открывает html-страницу внутри которой добавляет/изменяет данные с использованием `indexedDB`.
Вопросы:
1. Есть ли возможность как то откомпилировать React приложение в один/несколько файлов, перенести эти файлы на компьютер юзера, и подключить внутри html-страницы ? (Хочу использовать Ant Design)
2. Обязательно ли развертывать web-сервер на компьютере юзера ? Где почитать как это сделать на минималках ? И как задеплоить приложение ?
3. Может есть более простой способ/решение ? (как то откомпилировать в web-assembly)
Заранее благодарен за любые ответы !

Comment: Вам смотреть в сторону `PWA` приложений.

Answer (score -1):

1) Можно, также как вы переносите сайт для веб-сервиса. Точкой входа сделайте index.html. Можете заархивировать приложения и отправить. Пользователю нужно разорхивировать и запустить index.html.

2) Нет, браузер берёт на себя роль исполнителя.